# how to call store procedure from bteq in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I need to call a store procedure from BTEQ but I am unable to handle the Transaction error.

The script looks like below:

```
.logon xxx/xx,xx
CALL DD_LAB.MY_SP('a', 'b', outParam);
.logoff
```

Comment: What error? Your CALL looks ok.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.